# Access permissions for variable in Java

Tags: java, permissions

A certain class `Connection` has a field `int status`, which indicates the status of the connection. This field should be able publicly available for read, but not for writing, as only the object itself should write to that variable. Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: `private int status; public int getStatus()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should create public "getter" method for the private `status` field to prevent broken [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)):

```
private int status;
...
public int getStatus(){
    return this.status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set it as `private` and use a getter method to retrieve the value (i.e. encapsulate it).

Since it's a primitive, it's not mutable through a getter method.